# Mejor manera de generar un folio de base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [foliopoliza](
    [idfolio] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [upapoliza] [char](3) NULL,
    [documentopoliza] [char](2) NULL,
    [foliopoliza] [char](6) NULL,
    [ejercicio] [char](4) NULL,
    [fecharegistro] [datetime] NULL,
    [usuario] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idfolio] ASC
)
```

Y la tabla cuenta con los siguientes registros:

```
idfolio upapoliza   documentopoliza foliopoliza ejercicio       fecharegistro   usuario
1       PDR         02              0           2019         2019-05-06 14:02:57    DOS
2       PDR         02              0           2020         2019-05-06 14:02:57    DOS
```

Me indicaron que para generar el folio de otra tabla tengo que venir a esta tabla y **hacer update al campo** `foliopoliza + 1` para obtener el siguiente `id`, lo cual no se me hace muy seguro. ¿Hay alguna otra forma de generar folios que se generen desde la base de datos sin tener que estar haciendo **update** `campo+1` ? El problema es que en esta tabla ya no puedo usar `identity`(que me parece la mejor opción) porque ya lo tiene la columna `idfolio`.

**ACTUALIZACION:**
Esta es la tabla donde se pienza usar dicho folio:

```
CREATE TABLE [movimiento](
    [idmovimiento] [numeric](19, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ejercicio] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [claveupa] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [tipodoc] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [numero] [int] NOT NULL,
    [renglon] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dependencia] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [subdep] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ctacargo] [char](9) ,
    [ctaabono] [char](9) ,
    [importe] [numeric](15, 2) NOT NULL,
    [usuario] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [estatus] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [cheque] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [fecharegistro] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [fechaenvio] [datetime] NULL,
    [fechaentrega] [datetime] NULL,
    [observaciones] [varchar](100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idmovimiento] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [ukmovimiento] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ejercicio] ASC,
    [claveupa] ASC,
    [tipodoc] ASC,
    [numero] ASC,
    [renglon] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

El `foliopoliza` se piensa utilizar en el campo `numero` de esta tabla. De echo me plantearon la tabla con una llave compuesta con los campos del unique, pero eso no me pareció adecuado, por lo que yo agregue `idmovimiento` como primary key entera y agregue los campos de la llave compuesta al unique y así quite la llave compuesta.
Se supone que la tabla es para guardar cargos y abonos (contabilidad) de cheques y como pueden ser varios para un mismo cheque se creo el campo `renglon`

Comment: Hablar de _mejor_, siempre va a depender de las características que debe tener tu _folio_. Por ejemplo, es común que requieras un folio sin agujeros, es decir, va `1, 2, 3, 4`, no es válido `1, 3, 4, 6`. En un caso, la _mejor_ es una forma, en otro, puede ser otra. Por otro lado, si ya tienes el `id`, no puedes simplemente copiar ese valor al `folio`?

Comment: No puedo copiar el valor porque es `foliopoliza` es por año (ejercicio) y al hablar de mejor me refiero a aplicar las mejores practicas, es decir, no usar llaves compuestas o con cadenas o en este caso no darle el control de la generación de folios al programador, sino mantenerlo en base de datos, etc, etc.

Comment: No respondes a mi pregunta sobre los _agujeros_ del folio.

Comment: Es que eso también es parte de la pregunta. Necesito evaluar eso, pero para hacerlo necesitaría ver las posibles soluciones.Yo pensaría que no importan los agujeros, pero no se si después resulte que si importen.

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, esas son las cosas que se responden antes de plantear soluciones. Un saludo.

Comment: Identity no es una opcion para tu folio, ya que el mismo va dependiendo de registros en otra tabla. Te diria que hagas un trigger, pero concuerdo con @jachguate de que hay que saber absolutamente todas las reglas del negocio para ver cual es la mejor solucion. Tal vez si sea dejarselo al programador, ya que esto es una regla totalmente del negocio.. que pasa si el usuario cancela? que pasa si borra? que pasa si no termina la transaccion? En que momento de todos se graba ese folio? si dos usuarios quisieran agregar uno, quien gana?

Comment: Ese es el asunto, a mi me lo plantearon así, yo preferiría usar identity a una columna entera, pero debido a todos esos problemas que planteas es por lo que no se me hace seguro hacerlo así y me gustaría llegar con una propuesta alternativa, pero yo no me especializo en diseño de BD entonces generar una propuesta alternativa se me dificulta, es por eso que hice la pregunta

Comment: Y no, no hay cancelaciones ni borrados, y si la transacción no termina creo que no deberia incrementarse el folio

Comment: Ya actualice con mas información, espero que así ya me puedan ayudar a encontrar una solución.

Comment: tu idFolio lo puedes cambiar por foliopolizaId es necesario un id en esa tabla por cuestion de orden como indice y como llave de referencia para otras tablas, ahora tu campo usuario lo debes quitar de esa tabla porque si dos usuarios comporten la poliza estarias duplicando registros,  tu Folio puede ser un numero compuesto dependiendo de las reglas de negocio, ej Foliio=ejercicio+upapoliza+foliopolizaId

Comment: Quizá es factible una tabla intermedia que te relacione los folios de la tabla foliopoliza y  las polizas de la tabla movimientos. De esa manera puedes generar el siguiente id de la forma que prefieras en dicha tabla intermedia. Además facilitará realizar búsquedas de las polizas que pertenezcan a un folio. En el diseño actual no sé como podrías relacionar una poliza con un folio, si un ejercicio puede tener varios folios.

Comment: Podrías utilizar una secuencia y asignarla como dato por defecto a tu columna https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: upapoliza,documentopoliza y foliopoliza son  los campos que serian llave, yo tengo que generar foliopoliza el nombre de idFolio si tratare de cambiarlo @MiguelZarate

Comment: @Esteban En que campo me recomiendas aplicar la secuencia o como lo manejaria??

Comment: @JYass El folio es el identificador de una poliza por eso la tabla es foliopoliza es decir folio y poliza podrian decirse que es lo mismo. No intento relacionar con otra tabla, de hecho esta suelta la tabla, lo que intento es no tener que hacer update `foliopoliza+1` si no que lo genere la base de datos. Por eso me llama la atencion lo que propone @Esteban

Comment: @jachguate Ya estuve preguntando y es requerido que el foliopoliza no tenga saltos

Comment: Gracias a todos. He encontrado también este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback y dado el requisito de que el `foliopoliza` no tenga saltos parace que el identity tampoco es opción, creo que no me podre librar del update foliopoliza+1, pero ahora ¿Esta es la mejor forma de generar un folio sin saltos? Es decir, con `update foliopoliza+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que ha quedado claro que se requiere de un numerador de folios que no tenga saltos, considero que utilizar una tabla para llevar el contador es una buena y quizás la única alternativa viable que tienes.

Dicho en otras palabras, no vas a poder evitar el tan temido `update foliopoliza + 1`.

Lo que te sugiero, y es algo que te evitará uno que otro dolor de cabeza, es tener cuidado en el *orden* en que realizas estas operaciones, para evitar que se puedan duplicar los folios, que es el mayor riesgo de utilizar una tabla para llevar este control.

Para ello, sugiero que en tus operaciones hagas algo similar a lo siguiente:

- Primero, realizar todas las operaciones siguientes dentro del contexto de una misma transacción de base de datos, de manera que todas se confirmen (`commit`) o se reviertan (`rollback`) juntas.
- Luego, te asegures de poner un *lock* sobre el registro de la tabla `foliopoliza`. Esto se puede conseguir haciendo un `update` vacío a la tabla, por ejemplo:

  ```
  update foliopoliza 
     set foliopoliza = foliopoliza + 0 
   where ejercicio = 2019
         -- y otros campos que hagan único el registro.
  ```

  Esta acción es sumamente importante, pues este *bloqueo* provocará la serialización de otras transacciones que estén intentando tirar del mismo tipo de folio, obligandolas a esperar su turno, luego de que esta transacción termine, para poder tomar su valor.
- Las siguientes operaciones pueden realizarse en cualquier orden:

  - Puedes consultar el valor de foliopoliza que corresponde, con la seguridad que otras transacciones que estén compitiendo por el mismo folio se verán obligadas a esperar que se libere el *lock* que se ha puesto sobre la tabla, cosa que ocurrirá  cuando esta transacción haga `commit` o `rollback`.
  - Inserta o actualiza el/los registro/s en la tabla de transacciones, `movimiento`
  - Actualiza el valor que corresponde en foliopoliza, sumando el número de folios que has utilizado.
- Si ha habido algún error, hacer `rollback`. Si no ha habido error, hacer `commit`

Te lo digo así, en procedimiento, pues es algo que puedes hacer de varias maneras, por ejemplo, en la base de datos, dentro de un procedimiento almacenado o hasta en un trigger. También en una clase especializada en el manejo de folios en el lenguaje de alto nivel donde hagas el sistema que utiliza esta base de datos, o en cada lugar donde este sistema inserte registros en la base de datos (lo menos recomendado).

Debes tener especial cuidado en que la duración de las transacciones sea **el mínimo tiempo posible**, para evitar ver errores por contención en esta tabla.

La otra ventaja de este método es que si una transacción falla, es decir, termina con un `rollback`, no pasa nada con el correlativo, simplemente vuelve a su valor original.

Por otro lado, ya que necesitas que el consecutivo no tenga agujeros, te sugiero descartar de entrada utilizar otros objetos de la base de datos, como secuencias o columnas identity, pues no está garantizado que estos no tengan saltos, pues, por la propia concurrencia, sus valores no vuelven a su estado original en caso de un `rollback`.

Comment: Si bien entiendo, esto implica que el valor inicial de `foliopoliza` debe ser 1 y no 0, ya que el incremento de `foliopoliza` seria casi al final de la transacción, es correcto??.

Comment: Se puede hacer de cualquier manera, puedes almacenar el último valor y utilizar el valor + 1 para un nuevo folio, o puedes almacenar el _valor que toca_ y utilizar directamente ese. Es importante, eso si, que trabajes siempre de la misma manera, para evitar confusiones. Mi sugerencia es, encapsular la funcionalidad de alguna manera... funciones o clases y acudir a ellas siempre que necesitas gestionar un nuevo folio.

Comment: Gracias aplicare esta solución.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un [objeto de Sequencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql), precisamente son excelentes para estos casos.
Puedes reiniciar la secuencia cada periodo fiscal y determinar el rango.

El hecho de que el folio no tenga saltos es realmente complicado ya que ninguna solución que haya visto es totalmente confiable. Unas fallaran por transacciones canceladas y otras fallarán por acciones concurrentes que asignan el mismo número múltiples veces.

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece adecuada hasta cierto punto también, sobre todo donde dice: `El hecho de que el folio no tenga saltos es realmente complicado ya que ninguna solución que haya visto es totalmente confiable`. Aquí el asunto es que no puedo hacer comprender a usuarios faltos de conocimiento de computación he informática que el salto en los folios no es un error, sino una característica como se comenta aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/282495/600909 con lo cual aunque me parece adecuado no resuelve mi problema, razón por la cual no acepte esta respuesta. Aún así me parece un gran aporte.